# jQuery clone table row (DATA)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a table input form as per the picture. I want users to be able to enter just the first row (hostname, model, location, purchased, warranty fields) and then be able to hit 'Clone First Row' and it copies what they've entered to all the subsequent rows.

How best to do this in jQuery?

The rows are being generated in PHP with this code, and all have unique IDs:

```
<?php for($t = 1; $t <= 20; $t++){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="hostname-<?=$t;?>" class="form-control" id="hostname-<?=$t;?>"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="asset-tag-<?=$t;?>" class="form-control" id="asset-tag-<?=$t;?>"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="serial-<?=$t;?>" class="form-control" id="serial-<?=$t;?>"></td>
```

[image: Table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
    var firstRow = $("table").find("tr:first-child"),
        rowsToModify = firstRow.nextAll();
      
    firstRow.find(":input").each(function(idx) {
        rowsToModify.find(":input:eq(" + idx + ")").val(this.value);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="hostname-0" class="form-control" id="hostname-0"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="asset-tag-0" class="form-control" id="asset-tag-0"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="serial-0" class="form-control" id="serial-0"></td>
      <td>
        <select name="state-0" class="form-control" id="state-0">
          <option>Open</option>
          <option>Waiting</option>
          <option>Closed</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="hostname-1" class="form-control" id="hostname-1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="asset-tag-1" class="form-control" id="asset-tag-1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="serial-1" class="form-control" id="serial-1"></td>
      <td>
        <select name="state-1" class="form-control" id="state-1">
          <option>Open</option>
          <option>Waiting</option>
          <option>Closed</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="hostname-2" class="form-control" id="hostname-2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="asset-tag-2" class="form-control" id="asset-tag-2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="serial-2" class="form-control" id="serial-2"></td>
      <td>
        <select name="state-2" class="form-control" id="state-2">
          <option>Open</option>
          <option>Waiting</option>
          <option>Closed</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button">Clone values from first row</button>
```

Comment: Can't get this to work. My button is now: `<button type="button" id="clone" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Clone first row</button>`

Comment: The script shown isn't a fire&forget solution :) Did you change the selector to get the correct `<button/>` element? Can you show us the generated markup of the table plus the relevant parts of the script you're currently working with (in the question above) - [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Any errors in the console?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and your help :) On closer inspection your script does work, just not quite in the way I anticipated. Firstly, it will clone whatever input box currently has focus. It does not seem able to clone the two dropdowns, however. And my ideal scenario was for one click of the Clone button to clone the entire row onto the next. Is that possible?

Comment: I've adjusted my answer to clone all input elements available by the pseudo selector [`:input`](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) (input, textarea, select and button).